# ExtJS with React, scope confusion

Tags: javascript, reactjs, extjs

In my app I use ExtJS with React. I've tried to override some functionalities but I faced some problems when defining custom Ext components. I suspect that this is caused by different scopes of "this".

There are 2 scenarios. The 1st one is working scenario, but achieved in non-elegant way. The 2nd scenario is desired but it doesn't work.

---

**Scenario 1** - *it works* - [codepen #1](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KqXeqd?editors=1010)

*index.js*

```
// defined globally, it's not very nice
Ext.define('CustomContextMenu', {
    extend: 'Dummy.plugin.ContextMenu',
    createMenuItems: function() {
        return this.callParent() // keep standard behaviour
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(
    React.createElement(CustomScheduleApp),
    document.getElementById('schedule-app')
);
```

*app.jsx*

```
class CustomScheduleApp extends React.Component {
    ...
    render() {
        <CustomSchedule ...></CustomSchedule>
    }

}
```

*schedule.jsx*

```
class CustomSchedule extends React.Component {
    ...
    componentDidMount() {
        let taskContextMenu = Ext.create("CustomContextMenu");
        ...
    }
}
```

---

**Scenario 2** - *it **doesn't** work* - [codepen #2](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BZwqyv?editors=1010)

*index.js*

```
ReactDOM.render(
    React.createElement(CustomScheduleApp),
    document.getElementById('schedule-app')
);
```

*app.jsx*

```
class CustomScheduleApp extends React.Component {
    ...
    render() {
        <CustomSchedule ...></CustomSchedule>
    }

}
```

*schedule.jsx*

```
class CustomSchedule extends React.Component {
    ...
    componentDidMount() {
        Ext.define('CustomContextMenu', {
            extend: 'Dummy.plugin.ContextMenu',
            createMenuItems: function() {
                return this.callParent() // keep standard behaviour
                // "this" has fewer keys in this scenario, some data is missing
            }
        });

        let taskContextMenu = Ext.create("CustomContextMenu");
        ...
    }
}
```

Error message for Scenario #2:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of null
```

---

I have a basic knowledge about scopes, I'm not even sure if it's more React of JavaScript issue. Am I missing something in my code?

Comment: Are you using ExtReact or are you trying to integrate ExtJS with ReactJS yourself?

Comment: Thanks for response. I'm trying to integrate it by myself. To clarify- I'm using library that is built upon ExtJS.

Comment: Could you try and reproduce the issue using CodePen (https://codepen.io/)?

Comment: Yes, I've created two small snippets, I put them into description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the way React works and you are setting your extended method inside a React prototype, ExtJS `callParent` is getting confused about where the event is called from, so you would have to specify this manually.

```
addBodyCls: function(cls) {
     // custom logic here
     console.log("inside addBodyCls");
     return this.superclass.addBodyCls.apply(this, arguments);
 }
```

should do the trick!

Comment: Thank you very much! It helped me a lot.